# overriding new button on custom object how to do you access the opportunity id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, button-overrides

I'm trying to override the new button on one of my objects with a lightning component. If this object is being created on an opportunity is there a way to get the id of that opportunity? If you override the new button with a visualforce page you can access the opportunity id in the url, so I'm just curious if theres a similar way to get the opp id with a lightning component.

Comment: I have started development on my component. You mentioned it is possible, what are some good resources on how to go about this?

Comment: I just made a new button for casecomments from case object, I used force:hasrecordid in order to grab the case id and place it into the casecomment parentid field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to create a new child record on an Opportunity, using the New button on related list.

Your lightning component must implement **lightning:actionOverride** and **force:hasRecordId** interface. You must also manually override the New button on the child object with the lightning component you created.

Doing so, Salesforce will automatically add a **recordId** attribute on your component, with the Opportunity record Id.

In your client side controller or helper, you can fetch the Opportunity record id using **`component.get("v.recordId")`**.

Whenever a lightning component is embedded on the lightning record detail or page, lightning automatically adds the recordId in context, provided the hasRecordId interface has been implemented.

Salesforce document states that:

> The recordId attribute is set only when you place or invoke the component in an explicit record context. For example, when you place the component directly on a record page layout, or invoke it as an object-specific action from a record page or object home.

Comment: I tried this, but for me it does not work. I did an override on the 'new Case' button. Implemented the Lightning Component with actionOverride and hasRecordId. Then when I click on the 'New Case' button on the Account layout, there is no recordId to be found. It works however when I embed the Lightning Component directly on the Account Lightning Page, but that's not what we want. Are you sure your suggested solution works?

Comment: You actually cant use force:hasRecordId with an overridden "new" button. If you try overriding the "new" opportunity button on an Account related list, you'll find that component.get("v.recordId") is null. I can't tell you why, but this is definitely a fact.